# get a cell in the closest row of the previous year end

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, date

I have a row in mid year which I want to get the tax value of the previous year-end row.
Sometimes it will be `year-12-31` and sometime there will not be that date, but a few days before it.

[image]

So in `B17` I want to hold `B12`. There are dates for the last 10 years and only on `YYYY-03-08` I want to hold the previous year end tax value.

I tried `=MAX(IF(A2:A17<=DATE(YEAR(A17)-1,12,31),A2:A17))`
And `=MATCH(MAX(A2:A17-DATE(YEAR(A17)-1,12,31),0),A2:A17)`
no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are in sorted order and you are able to use a third column, then flag when the year changes from one row to the next.

In cell C2 and copied down:
`=IF(YEAR(A3)-YEAR(A2)=1,YEAR(A2),"")`

In cell B17:
`=INDEX(B2:B16,MATCH(YEAR(A17)-1,C2:C16,0),1)`

The above formulas assume that the data is as presented in your image and was tested on Excel 2010.